# In Selenium, Unable to switch to the main Window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know there is a glitch in my code, can you please tell me why am i unable to switch to the main window.

I am trying to open multiple windows and using a Method to switch to the main Window, and close only a desired window, if its title matches with the string i hard-coded in the code. Sorry for posting the whole code, just cannot figure out where the error is in my code. Help me,if you can! Thanks for reading.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MutiWindowsnaukri {


public static void multiWind(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{

        Iterator<String>it =  driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();


        while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("switching to mainWindow");
        String mWind =   it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(mWind);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(6000L);
        }

          }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://www.naukri.com");
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Post Jobs")).click();
multiWind(driver);
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Employer Zone")).click();
multiWind(driver);
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Employer Zone")).click();
multiWind(driver);
Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Report a Problem")).click();
multiWind(driver);
                  Set<String>s2 = driver.getWindowHandles();
       Iterator<String> it1=    s2.iterator();
       // Iterator<String> it1 = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
//Iterator<String>it1 =  (Iterator<String>) driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
        String str ="Post";
while(it1.hasNext()){
driver.switchTo().window(it1.next());
String title = driver.getTitle();

if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
driver.close();
break;
}

}

}

}
```

Error:

```
switching to mainWindow
Jobs - Recruitment - Job Search - Employment - Job Vacancies - Naukri.com
switching to mainWindow
Jobs - Recruitment - Job Search - Employment - Job Vacancies - Naukri.com
switching to mainWindow
Post Jobs – Job posting Site – Post Vacancy Naukri.com
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Employer Zone
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Comment: 1. Maybe I'm wrong, but per my understanding in multiWind you're iterating-switching over all windows and stop at the last opened window. Which is "Post Jobs", at the first time you invoke multiWind() after ("Post Jobs")).click(). 
2. Selenium doesn't automatically switch to a new opened window. Actiive window remains the same. So, don't need to use multiWind() after each click, since all links are on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for writing back, I have to switch to the main window, since the new page is getting open in the tab,not in the new window altogether. without using a method it works perfectly fine, i just wanted to try with a method.for an example:
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Employer Zone")).click();
     driver.switchTo().window(main);

Comment: If you like to see the complete code where i need to switch to main window after clicking each link, in which i didn't use any method , you can view this link http://rextester.com/AAOL28575

Comment: I believe tab = window from selenium point of view.

Comment: The obvious difference between you code snippets is that in complete code version you switch to main window by earlier saved handle. Whereas in code from the question multiWind function you consequently switch between **all** windows. The last window in the list is the **last** opened window. And not the main one. So you're effectively switching to the last window.

By the way, you could get current window handle with driver.getWindowHandle() (see complete code lines 25-26)

Comment: Can you sum up the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_